# Extracting multiple url address from excel cell /excel file

Tags: excel, regex, vba, excel-formula

I have multiple cells at excel like the one below and I want to extract all the URLs which start with "https://images"

```
<div id="images-gallery" class="slick-carousel slick-carousel-arrow-style-2" data-was-processed="true"><div class="gallery-thumb" data-src="https://images.mytestdomain.gr/image1.jpg" data-idx="1"><picture>
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/44x44-90_jpg/%CE%BA%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B4%CF%86.webp" media="(max-width: 768px)">
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/60x60-90_jpg/%CE%BA%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B4%CF%86.webp" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
img src="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/105x105-90/%CE%BA%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B4%CF%86.jpg" alt="Oral-B 3D White Brilliance Οδοντόβουρτσα για Λευκά Δόντια 1 τεμάχιο" title="Oral-B 3D White Brilliance Οδοντόβουρτσα για Λευκά Δόντια 1 τεμάχιο" class="loaded" data-was-processed="true">
</picture></div><div class="gallery-thumb" data-src="https://images.mytestdomain.gr/3014260090890bbbbbbbbb.jpg" data-idx="2"><picture>
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/44x44-90_jpg/3014260090890bbbbbbbbb.webp" media="(max-width: 768px)">
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/60x60-90_jpg/3014260090890bbbbbbbbb.webp" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/78x78-90_jpg/3014260090890bbbbbbbbb.webp" media="(max-width: 1280px)">
<img src="https://cdn.mytestdomain.gr/photos/small/105x105-90/3014260090890bbbbbbbbb.jpg" alt="Oral-B 3D White Brilliance Οδοντόβουρτσα για Λευκά Δόντια 1 τεμάχιο" title="Oral-B 3D White Brilliance Οδοντόβουρτσα για Λευκά Δόντια 1 τεμάχιο" class="loaded" data-was-processed="true">
</picture></div></div>
```

So I am using this function but I only get one result. Is there any way to make it work for multiple results or use another function? Thank you.

Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtrUrls(S As String) As String()
    Dim sTemp() As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "https?:\/\/(images\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9á-ùÁ-Ù()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)" 'Regex for emails
    Dim i As Long
    
'Initialize Regex engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ReDim sTemp(1 To MC.Count)
        i = 0
        For Each M In MC
            i = i + 1
            sTemp(i) = M
        Next M
    End If
End With
ExtrUrls = sTemp
End Function
```

At this image you can see what I want to achieve. At the left cell I have some URLs but when I call the function I want to get as a result the content of the right cell(all the URLs which start with "https://images")
I call the function by writing **=ExtrUrls(A14)**
[image]

Comment: Exactly how are you calling this?  It works for me when entered in a row of cells as an array formula.  It will not work in a *column* of cells because the returned array is "the wrong way around"

Comment: I call the function by writting =ExtrUrls(A14)

Answer (score 1):

Edit - If you just want a single string, then instead of creating an array just append each M to a string and return that. Change your function return type to String and not String()

```vb
Function ExtrUrls(S As String) As String
    Dim rv As String, sep as String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "https?:\/\/(images\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9á-ùÁ-Ù()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)" 'Regex for emails
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Initialize Regex engine
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Pattern = sPat
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        If .Test(S) Then
            Set MC = .Execute(S)
            For Each M In MC
                rv = rv & sep & M
                sep = ";" 'or whatever separator you want
            Next M
        End If
    End With

    ExtrUrls = rv
End Function
```

---

Your UDF works for a row of cells when entered as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

If you're calling this from a *column* of cells as an array formula, you can "flip" the array:

```vb
Function ExtrUrls(s As String) ' As String()
    Dim sTemp() 'As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "https?:\/\/(images\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9á-ùÁ-Ù()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)" 'Regex for emails
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Initialize Regex engine
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Pattern = sPat
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        If .Test(s) Then
            Set MC = .Execute(s)
            ReDim sTemp(1 To MC.Count)
            i = 0
            For Each M In MC
                i = i + 1
                sTemp(i) = M
            Next M
        End If
    End With
    
    'if called from a column of cells, then flip the array
    On Error Resume Next  'ignore error when not called as a UDF
    Set rng = Application.Caller
    On Error GoTo 0        'stop ignoring errors
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then sTemp = Application.Transpose(sTemp)
    End If
    
    ExtrUrls = sTemp
End Function
```

Comment: I tried using this function but i still get only one url as a result.. Is there any way to save all the results to a string and then return that string to the cell? Thank you.

Comment: If you just want a single string then instead of creating an array just append each `M` to a string and return that.  Change your function return type to `String` and not `String()`